# Calling arrays and data in D3

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I've been coding in D3 from a while now but there's bits about it that still leave me stumped. I've got some data in a csv file. I'm calling it in the following way

```
var dataset;     
d3.tsv("ST_03_data.tsv", function(data) {       
dataset=data;
```

and then I do a whole bunch of things like drawing a graph or whatever and it's fine. I'd like to use some, but not all, of the columns of data in a certain way, so what I'd like to do is set them up as a variable. So what I've done, straight away underneath the code above is write

```
var newvar = (d.data1, d.data3, d.data5)
```

where data1, data3 and data5 are columns of data.  get the error message "Can't find variable d". If if use (data1, data3, data5) instead (that is, dropping the d.) I get an equivalent message.

So what's going wrong? Do I need to build a function? I've sort of tried and that hasn't worked either but  can see how it might be better. All help appreciated. Thanks.

There's a full example here -http://www.graphitti.org/admin2/files/experiments/click_counter3.html It looks like it works and it does up to a point but I want to make it easier. At the moment, there are two clicks, and clicking them passes new data in. It does so using variables I have set up in each click, in fact in the attributes for the rectangles. What I want to do is move that variable (called barup at the moment) to the top of the code so I don't need to repeat it.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. You're only defining `dataset` and `data` in your code, so where do `d`, `data1`, etc come from?

Comment: They're the names of the columns in the tsv file. As to what I'm trying to do, that is a very good question. Ultimately, I've got a click handler later in the code and when you click it different columns in the dataset get selected to draw a line graph. But I don't need every column, just some of them.

Comment: Well then you would need to do `dataset.data1` or something like that to access the columns.

Comment: (edit) I've now had a go at that and it If I put, say console.log(dataset[1]) it will return the second row of the dataset. But if I put console.log(dataset.1), it doesn't return anything - it says it's undefined. How do I get columns, rather than rows?

Comment: Like I said, `dataset.data1` where `data1` is the name of a column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54457/discussion-between-tom-macinnes-and-lars-kotthoff).

Comment: So what's the problem with moving the definition of `barup` up?

Comment: The problem is just that it comes back undefined - in the console log you can see I get [undefined, undefined]. So when I try to use that to set the height of the bars, it comes back as NaN